# c# use .net 4.5 compiled dll, in a .net 4.0 application

Tags: c#, .net

Long story short, I have a console based application that **must** be backwards compatible to XP. It is compiled in .net 4.0

I need functionality of 4.5 for zip management and **cannot** be third party. I have added the functionality to a .net 4.5 compiled dll

is it even possible to have these two "talk" and "play nice"

Comment: Even if they could, the 4.5 assembly couldn't run on XP.

Comment: That's not possible of course, surely this is obvious?

Comment: It is possible but its hell of a lot of work, firstly you have to remove all default libraries from your code and then directly link in the DLL and mark as a copy local, then you have to ensure that none of the libraries require a windows 7+ system library that isn't present in XP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.dll`s of different frameworks can certainly interact without too many problems... However, in your case, you're out of luck...

The `.dll` that is `.NET 4.5` will require the `.NET 4.5 framework` to be installed on your XP machine.  Which of course, you can't do.

So the answer is: **No**.

Comment: I figured it would be something like that. Thanks - why microsoft why.... after devs hunt for so long for .net functionality integrated into .net, that same release they break all backwards compatability...

Comment: @asuppa, [Windows XP mainstream support has ended on April 14, 2009](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows/products/lifecycle). So the question is why you are still using XP.

Comment: @asuppa: To be fair... XP is older than some of the programmers on SO.

Comment: @Habib its for xpmode, - and really I couldnt tell you I code what I am told :)

Comment: @andrew, that is fair, i mean even now that xp has been discontinued for a while, (years?) it still feels like its still got a majority, even if its just through xpmode on the newwer systems.

Comment: you can do it but its not worth the effort, i once needed a net 2.0 dll on a net 1.1 machine and it worked but was a nightmare

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that. It will be following compile time error.

"< Class Name >" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".”

Comment: Thats what I was comming accross Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible under 2 conditions, 1 you are providing a full installer for the product and 2 the library you require is not using a system dll not available on the target machine

99.9999% of the time this is just not worth it

basically what you need to do is install the required Dll's (remebering that required is defined as the ones you need and every one that thet rely upon aswell) from the framework that isn't installed on the target machine as a purely local resource for the program.

that can mean recompiling large numbers of .nets DLLs to break the framework links

personally i would suggest using a 3rd party zip libray like [sharpZiplib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)